# Bricked android lg g stylo metropcs

Tags: unbricking, lg-g-stylo

I need help with my lg g stylo. I was using one click root Kingo root and when it was 66% done it was rebooting my phone into firmware download and my computer running Windows 10 froze to where I had to hard reset it, and my phone froze on firmware update.

Now my phone is stuck in a bootloop on the LG life's good screen, I've tried hard resetting it ( with the volume down and power button combo) the Android guy pops up for one millisecond and disappears going back to the LG screen, not doing anything the only other the only other thing I can do is go into downloading mode( while connected to a computer hold the volume button up) but when I do that my computer does not recognize my phone saying code 10 device cannot start up.

I have called LG they refused to help me get into recovery mode. I have called Google Android support they don't know how to help, I have also called windows trying to see if it was my computer's fault and they decided it wasn't. I am kind of out of options, I'm hoping someone knows how to help me.

Comment: Can you get into Recovery Mode?  If not please try steps 1-6 [here](http://gadgetspie.com/2015/07/12/root-t-mobile-metropcs-lg-g-stylo-on-android-5-1-1-lollipop/).

Comment: No I am unable to access recovery, and when i called LG customer support they refused to tell me how. I kind of tried that already with Android Studio/Android SDK Manager with adb and fastboot plugins. When I try looking for my device with (adb devices) it says, list of devices and then nothing after that, just a new command line. I have the USB drivers for LG. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled them a few times. Any suggestions?

Comment: There should be a key combo to get into factboot mode without using adb, on many devices it's Power+VolumeUp.

Comment: I've looked on Google for ways to and the T-Mobile version of my phone has a way to, but the button combo (vol down and power at same time when lg appears release both then press both again until recovery mode appears) doesn't work for metroPCS version.